# Encrypting sound files using RSA and Java

Tags: java, file-io, cryptography, rsa

So, I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt sound files using Java's RSA library. It works without a problem when I'm doing it with Strings, and I have studied RSA encryption, so I know what I'm doing. The problem must be with handling files or BigIntegers.

Code for encrypting bytes in a file, then decrypting it and putting it in a new file:

```
            File sound = new File("F://java/Projekt kryptering/ljudtest.wma");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(sound);
            int fragSize = 200;
            ArrayList<BigInteger> encryptedFragments = new ArrayList<BigInteger>((int)(sound.length()/fragSize)); //create an aproximation on number of BigIntegers required
            byte byt;
            byte[] buf = new byte[fragSize];
            int bufPos = 0;
            while((byt = (byte)fr.read()) != -1){
                buf[bufPos++] = byt;
                if(bufPos == fragSize){
                    BigInteger soundFrag = new BigInteger(buf);
                    System.out.println("unencrypted bigInt: " + soundFrag);
                    encryptedFragments.add(soundFrag.modPow(pub.getPublicExponent(), pub.getModulus()));
                    bufPos = 0;
                }
            }
            fr.close();

            File decryptedSound = new File("F://java/Projekt kryptering/ljudtest2.wma");
            decryptedSound.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(decryptedSound);
            for(BigInteger frag : encryptedFragments){
                BigInteger decrypted = frag.modPow(priv.getPrivateExponent(), priv.getModulus());
                System.out.println("decrypted frag " + decrypted);
                byte[] frags = decrypted.toByteArray();
                for(byte fragg : frags)
                    fw.write(fragg);
            }
            fw.close();
```

What happens when i try to do it is that the resulting file only becomes 276 bytes (the original file is 22,3kB). You can also see some Sytem.outs in the code and here's the result from those:

```
unencrypted bigInt: <Very long number>
unencrypted bigInt: <Very long number 2>
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
unencrypted bigInt: 0
decrypted frag <Very long number 3>
decrypted frag <Very long number 4
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
decrypted frag 0
```

Comment: RSA isn't suitable for something like this. You need a block cipher such as AES.

Comment: @Kayaman Not to mention that the JRE has a cryptography library that support RSA – you don't need to roll your own. However, if you are doing this just for fun or something, it's worth noting that `new BigInteger(byte[])` can create negative BigIntegers (use the other constructor that also takes an int instead), and that `BigInteger.toByteArray()` "drops" leading zeros.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Which is why the RSA specification explicitly defines an I2OS algorithm for representing integers as octet strings (aka byte arrays).

Comment: @SiXoS You should not be using remarks such as "... so I know what I'm doing". Even accomplished cryptographers make implementation mistakes, and almost always these kind of sentences come back to haunt you. I would say that most accomplished cryptographers have learned not to make such claims (excepting Daniel Bernstein probably, but he's gained some bragging rights).

Comment: @ntoskrnl I didn't find methods for encrypting and decrypting, only how to generate keys. So I used the generated keys to encrypt the data according to RSA. But after some breif searching i found the Cipher class, will try that.

Comment: @owlstead Ok, I can agree on that. I just wanted to tell that my file or BigInteger management were more likely to cause my problems.

Comment: Unfortunately your implementation of RSA is lacking in a lot of departments. Please have a look at the OAEP specifications in PKCS#1 or the related [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447). RSA without padding is not secure.